# Unity - Calculate the Duration of one Orbit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a Sun with a Position (0,500,0) and a Rotation of (90,0,0). The sun is rotating around Vector3.zero with a speed of 10.

The Script is

```
void RotateLight(Light light) // Sun is orbitting the Earth
    {
        light.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.right, timeData.RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // Rotate around the Earth
        light.transform.LookAt(Vector3.zero); // Face the Earth
    }
```

So I want to use the GUI to show the maximum duration of one orbit. Also I need to calculate the current state of the sun.

So I calculate the maximum duration:

```
public float DayCycleLength // one full cyclus
    {
        get
        {
            return 2 * Mathf.PI * Distance / RotationSpeed; // Distance -> The Distance from sun to earth -> 500 ### Rotationspeed -> The speed of the sun -> 10
        }
    }
```

I want to know if this seems to be correct?

I do not know, how to calculate the current state of the sun.

When I got these two information I could show it with a Slider element of the Unity UI System.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Your method `DayCycleLength` should be called `YearCycleLength` if you're trying to calculate the orbit duration. </pedant>

Comment: Thanks, could you help me out with the calculation of the current state too?

Comment: Well the distance is `2*pi*radius` so you have that right. If the speed is using the same units (i.e. miles per hour when distance is in miles also) then you divide by that. So it looks like you have it right. Do you think it might be wrong?

Comment: No no :) The only thing left is the current state. ... Where is the sun in the moment X ... I got the maximum duration and the speed but I do not know how to calc the current time.

Comment: What do you mean by "current state of the sun" then? You mean the position?

Comment: I got a Slider with a value range from 0 to 1. So "DayCycleLength" should represent 1. So the Slider needs to know, where the current value is at. The "currentValue" has to be between 0 and 1 then.

Comment: Uh...the length of a day is not determined by the duration of the orbit - it's based on the rotation of the planet relative to the sun. (When the earth orbits once around the sun, that's not a day...that's a *year*.) What are you actually trying to calculate here?

Comment: I have a Day/Night Cycle in Unity. The Sun rotates around the Vector (0,0,0). To show the cycle, I made a Slider element for the player UI. This slider has the value Range from 0 to 1. So what do I need to calculate there to use the Slider correctly? I think I need the maximum duration and the current state. And that is whats missing

Comment: To reiterate - length of a day is independent of the orbit around the sun. The length of 1 Earth day is when it completes a full rotation *spinning on its axis*. The length of 1 Earth year is when it completes a full orbit around the sun. Your slider should affect how fast the planet spins on its axis, aka. How long it takes for it to complete one full rotation/one day. If you want to affect how fast the planet orbits around the sun, then you should make another slider dictating the year length. (The confusion here is it's not clear which metric you actually want to control.)